# Why does downvoting affect your own reputation?

Tags: discussion

I just downvoted an answer for the first time today, and noticed that I lost 1 reputation score. Obviously 1 "point" isn't a big deal. Whoop-dee-doo!

But on a serious note, what's the reasoning behind this?

My guess:
Discourage users from unnecessarily downvoting on things, so that only, truly, those questions/answers are "bad" are downvoted upon?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/privileges/vote-down Down votes on *answers* cost, down votes on *questions* are free.

Comment: With the ability to edit questions and answers, it is hoped that when something is *slightly* off course you can improve it with an edit rather than downvote it when it could easily be "saved". The other option of course is to ignore it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Discourages users from unnecessarily downvoting on things, so that only, truly, those questions/answers are "bad" are downvoted upon.

Comment: And yet there is no dis-incentive to curb upvoting, even when the questions or answers are absurd or totally incorrect.

Comment: @JohnGardeniers Something something "you can't fix stupid" murmer murmer. Although I highly doubt ServerFault will ever have an upward spiral of voting. We're rather lethargic about that with only a handful of *cough* notable exceptions. =)

Comment: I feel like I should make a witty comment here, but I can't think of anything...

Comment: @Ward *Upvoted!*

Comment: @John Gardeniers: yes, there is a dis-incentive to curb upvoting: daily reputation cap

Comment: @longneck, you, and whoever upvoted your comment, appear to have misunderstood things a bit. The daily cap only limits the rep a person can *receive* and is unrelated to the upvotes a person *casts*. Maybe you're thinking of the daily voting limit but that also is no dis-incentive against upvoting.

Answer (score 6):

Correct!

Comment: I downvoted you to test if I get -1 rep.

Comment: @Legit - it doesn't work on Meta; there are no rep changes here except what happens on the main site

Comment: @Legit, you do gain badges for some pretty whacky reasons on meta, although those badges are distinct from the ones you get on SF, unlike the rep which is common to both SF and MSF. Some things of Stack Exchange simply defy logic.